# Why does G_IS_OBJECT (object) fail for Gio.PropertyAction.new?

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

In a python3/pygobjects/gtk+3 application I’m trying to control a property through togglebuttons via `Gio.PropertyAction`. Unfortunately I don’t seem to be able to create the action.

I have boiled it down to this minimal example:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gio, Gtk, GObject

class Obj(GObject.GObject):
    prop = GObject.property(type = int)

    def __init__(self):
        action = Gio.PropertyAction.new('act', self, 'prop')

obj = Obj()
```

It yields this error:

```
(test.py:9099): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_property_action_new: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 11, in <module>
    obj = Obj()
  File "./test.py", line 9, in __init__
    action = Gio.PropertyAction.new('act', self, 'prop')
TypeError: constructor returned NULL
```

According to the [Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/objects.html) this is the correct way to handle properties. Curiously though, the [Python GI API Reference](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/) does not know of `GObject.GObject`, but has only `GObject.Object` and requires it as second argument for `Gio.PropertyAction.new` (compare [Gio.PropertyAction.new](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/PropertyAction.html#Gio.PropertyAction.new)).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is, that I did not call the parent constructor, i.e. the one of `GObject.GObject`. The following works:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gio, Gtk, GObject

class Obj(GObject.GObject):
    prop = GObject.property(type = int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        action = Gio.PropertyAction.new('act', self, 'prop')

obj = Obj()
```